# EJB 3 + JPA2 = Deserialized Object with null fields

Tags: java, persistence, ejb-3.0, jpa-2.0, entitymanager

I have a JPA Annotated Object and a EJB remote interface in one jar and the EJB Stateless implementation with the Entity Manager injected deployed in a war file. My client creates a new instance of the object and sends it across the wire.

However when it is deserialized on the server side, the object has null for every field, plus is contains other fields like `_persistence_primaryKey`. It seems that the server implementation thinks that my deserialized object is already managed...but its not...how do I pass the object across the wire so its deserialized properly? If the entity manager is commented out, the object deserializes just fine.

See below for code example:

**Chicken.java (JPA Annotated POJO)**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Chicken")
public class Chicken implements Serializable{

    /**
     *serial version id 
     */
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     @Id
     @Column(name="ID")
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long id;

     @Column(name="NAME")
     private String name;

     public Chicken(){
     }

     public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
     }

     public String getName(){
         return name;
     }
}
```

**ChickenCreator.java (Stateless EJB w/ JPA injection)**

```
@Stateless
public class ChickenCreator implements ChickenCreatorRemote{

  @PersistenceContext(unitName="DataStore") private EntityManager em;

  public ChickenCreator(){
  }

  public createChicken(Chicken chicken){
     em.persist(chicken);
  }

}
```

**ChickenClient.java (JSF UI with injected Remote EJB Interface)**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public ChickenClient(){

    @EJB private ChickenCreatorRemote ccr;

    public void makeChicken(){
       Chicken chicken = new Chicken();
       chicken.setName("Bob");
       ccr.createChicken(chicken);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue may be comes from this problem http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16164

I had same issue in Glassfish 3.1.1 with separate `EAR and WAR`.
This property in persistence.xml solved my issue:

```
&lt;property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/&gt;
```

Comment: Thanks. Using the <property name="eclipselink.weaving.fetchgroups" value="false"/> workaround described in the bug link worked for me, while still allowing weaving for lazy-loading.